# Cleaning a text file for csv export

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to cleanup a text file from a URL using pandas and my idea is to split it into separate columns, add 3 more columns and export to a csv.

I have tried cleaning up the file (I believe it is being separated by " ") and so far no avail.

```
# script to check and clean text file for 'aberporth' station
import pandas as pd
import requests

# api-endpoint for current weather
URLH = "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/stationdata/aberporthdata.txt"

with requests.session() as s:
    # sending get for histroy text file
    r = s.get(URLH)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text), sep=" ", skiprows=5, error_bad_lines=False)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text), nrows=1)
    # df1['location'] = df2.columns.values[0]
    # _, lat, _, lon = df2.index[0][1].split()
    # df1['lat'], df1['lon'] = lat, lon
    df1.dropna(how='all')
    df1.to_csv('Aberporth.txt', sep='|', index=True)
```

What makes it worse is that the file itself has uneven columns, and somewhere down line 944, it adds one more column for which I to skip error on bad lines. At this point I'm a bit lost as for how I should proceed and if I should look at something else beyond Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need pandas for this. The built-in `csv` module does just fine.

The data comes in fixed-width format (which is not the same as "delimited format"):

```
Aberporth
Location: 224100E 252100N, Lat 52.139 Lon -4.570, 133 metres amsl
Estimated data is marked with a * after the value.
Missing data (more than 2 days missing in month) is marked by  ---.
Sunshine data taken from an automatic Kipp & Zonen sensor marked with a #, otherwise sunshine data taken from a Campbell Stokes recorder.
   yyyy  mm   tmax    tmin      af    rain     sun
              degC    degC    days      mm   hours
   1942   2    4.2    -0.6    ---     13.8    80.3
   1942   3    9.7     3.7    ---     58.0   117.9
   ...
```

So we can either split it at predefined indexes (which we would have to count & hard-code, and which probably are subject to change), or we can split on "multiple spaces" using regex, in which case it does not matter where the exact column positions are:

```
import requests
import re
import csv

def get_values(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)

    for line in resp.text.splitlines():
        values = re.split("\s+", line.strip())

        # skip all lines that do not have a year as first item
        if not re.match("^\d{4}$", values[0]):
            continue

        # replace all '---' by None
        values = [None if v == '---' else v for v in values]
        yield values



url = "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/stationdata/aberporthdata.txt"

with open('out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    writer.writerows(get_values(url))
```

You can do `writer.writerow(['yyyy','mm','tmax','tmin','af','rain','sun'])` to get a header row if you need one.